# Extended IdentityUser returns null on relation property

Tags: c#, sql, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I'm having a little trouble to fix an probably error in my code.

I have an Application user class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public decimal Status { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Income> Incomes { get; set; }
}
```

An Income class

```
public class PaymentBase : BaseEntity
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Value { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    //relations
    public string ApplicationUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }
}

public class Income : PaymentBase
{
    public IncomeCategory IncomeCategory { get; set; }
}
```

An ProjectDbContext class

```
public class ProjectDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>, IDisposable
{
    public ProjectDbContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<RefreshToken> RefreshTokens { get; set; }
    public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<ApplicationUser> ApplicationUsers { get; set; }
    public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<Expense> Expenses { get; set; }
    public Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbSet<Income> Incomes { get; set; }

    public override Task<int> SaveChangesAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        return base.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
    }

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

And when i'm trying to get an ApplicationUser with relation to Income it's returning null at a property. 
I've probably tried every solution but none of these works propery.

What's more, when I am adding an new Income then in Database I have an entry In Table Incomes on column ApplicationUserId that directly references to AspNetUser Id.

That's how I am trying to retrive the data :

```
var findByIdAsync = _context.ApplicationUsers
            .Include(x => x.Incomes)
            .FirstOrDefault<ApplicationUser>(x => x.Id == userId);
```

And via this query I am getting ApplicationUser but Incomes are null.

Do you know any solution for that?

Comment: Why is your application user id field a string inside payment base?

Comment: @VidmantasBlazevicius on database in table AspNetUser the ID field has "Text" Type, and the "IdentityUser" class inherits an "IdentityUser<string>"

Comment: What does the generated SQL look like?

Comment: @DevilSuichiro Long story short: Select * from AspNetUsers